# Set max height for box available from parent minus other child element in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 boxes one of fixed aspect ratio 16/9 and I want to set 2nd box to be the size of the remaining space.

The box with an aspect ratio of 16/9 is at the bottom.

[image]

I want the white part to be filled with a magenta box of width max and height responsive.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Box {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                        .background(color = Color.Magenta)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(16 / 9f)
                        .background(color = Color.Red)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(
    showBackground = true, name = "Light mode",
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO or Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL
)
@Preview(
    showBackground = true, name = "Night mode",
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES or Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL
)
@Composable
fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    HomeScreen()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this, [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) should be used: with the default parameter `fill = true` it will force the view to take up all the height remaining after the other unweighted children.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .weight(1f)
        .background(color = Color.Magenta)
)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .aspectRatio(16 / 9f)
        .background(color = Color.Red)
)
```